# Datatables.net: Correct serverside pagination with React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, datatables, pagination

I have a react component that makes a request to an API using redux. This request performs a server-side pagination.

The problem is I don't understand how to perform this pagination in datatables.net using redux.

I do know how to perform a pagination without datatables (actually, my component is performing it) and datatables has a [ajax support](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax), as the [react-redux-datatable](https://github.com/kenforthewin/react-redux-datatable) package. Both perform directs call to API through ajax, that is not the case of using redux.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

//...

const [skip, setSkip] = useState(10)
const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

// offset = 0 to page 0, offset 10 to page 1, offset 20 to page 2 and so on
<button onClick={() => props.doList({ offset: page * skip  })}>Request</button>

// Table shows the current 10 entries, from a max that is also 10.
<Table data={props.list} columns={predefinedColums}>

//...

// results are acessed by props.list
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return ({
        list: state.reducer.list,
    })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            doList,
        },
        dispatch
    )
```

Currently, I can show the desired results, but don't know how to perform new calls  on page change in the datatable component. The pagination API is working, so if I change manually the page number, it returns the correct entries.

```js
//Table component

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'datatables.net'
import 'datatables.net-responsive'
import 'datatables.net-select'

// other imports

function Table(props) {
    const { columns, data, title } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        $('#table_id').DataTable().destroy()
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            data,
            columns,
            "responsive": true,
            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": i18n.t('emptyDataSourceMessage'),
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": i18n.t('Previous'),
                    "next": i18n.t('Next'),
                    "first": i18n.t("First"),
                    "last": i18n.t("Last"),
                },
                "infoFiltered": i18n.t("(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)"),
                "search": i18n.t('Search'),
                "info": i18n.t("Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries"),
                "infoEmpty": i18n.t("Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries"),
            },
        })
    }, [columns, data])

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12">
                <div class="section section-data-tables">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-content">
                            <h4 className="card-title">{title}</h4>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col s12">
                                    <table id="table_id" className="display">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                {columns.map((column, key) => <th key={key} data-field={column.field}>{column.title}</th>)}
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                {columns.map((column, key) => <th key={key} data-field={column.field}>{column.title}</th>)}
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

The table looks like: (showing 10 results of 10 and only page)

[image]

I would like to know how to perform a server side pagination correctly with redux. Is currently possible to know the number of entries and also the current page to be displayed.

Comment: If the server is doing the pagination, then in each request it should tell how many entries in total there are, what's the limit u r using, what's the page u r in, and probably whether there is a next page or not, which will solve the HOW to do it in Redux, if u have these information from the API I'm pretty sure u can handle the rest.

Comment: Yeah, the problem actually is by using redux, because the pagination itself could be easy made using the ajax property. By using redux, it's like to have the data ready to use, but only for one page instead to have all data to paginate in frontend. As I can have a million of registers, get all data is not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Just slice out the part of the results you want to return to the client (see first code section below).
Also, what I do when doing server-side pagination is caching the result of the request using a unique id. This is almost mandatory to prevent the multiple re-compute of the search every time the user switch of page number or page size.

I request some results as the following:

1. Client: Send the search (it can also be a category id) request.
2. Server: Convert the search to the unique id. See if the result is already in cache. If no, compute the search, put in cache, the key being the unique id. Using common array operations (slice) on the search results, I take only the desired part.

```js
ret.productIDs =ret.productIDs.slice(imports.config.pageSizes[req.body.pageSize]*(req.body.pageNum), imports.config.pageSizes[req.body.pageSize]*(req.body.pageNum+1));
```

3. Server: return it alongside with the search unique id (so that next time it can directly use this id instead of the search).
4. Client: Display the search results. Whenever the user changes the page size or page num, send this request:

   ```
   {
       searchId, pageNum, pageSizeIndex
   }
   ```

Now you can also extend this to sortings, using a sortingIndex. Plus on server, you keep a record of the available sortings of a search result being in cache. If the one asked by the user is not yet computed, just sort one of the available (already computed sortings), and add it to the available sortings of the cache entry (for this search result).
So the final request actually looks like:

```
{
    searchId, pageNum, pageSizeIndex, sortingIndex
}
```

Comment: Seems an alternative, but seems it makes the request less flexible, for example, to use the search field, that probably would change the cache rules, except if I also cache this one in a single Id.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I'm been clear, and I'm not sure to understand what bothers you ^^ If you forget about the cache, and focus on the pagination aspect, which is just the use of slice on the search result to cut the part the user need, is it better ? The request would then look like: 
     { search (or categoryId, or anything categorizing the data you want to get), pageNum, pageSizeIndex }

Comment: the problem actually is by using redux, not with the pagination itself. As using redux, I need some event to trigger the new request to get the next page, it works well as an API call. The problem is I cannot bind the redux call to a click in the page button (as a "on change" trigger)

Comment: Then can I suggest you to have a look to the [Redux Real World Example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) ? It shows how to use pagination, have a look to the [pagination reducer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/reducers/paginate.js).

Comment: and [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#note-on-nested-entities) also

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself badly. I can perform the pagination with redux, and it's ok to manipulate it in an other component like [this one](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) pagination way. In this case, I can call the reducer once I click in a page number, binding the call to an "onPageChange" event and controlling manually the number of pages, response and etc. But as datatables does everything, I don't know how to bind the redux call to a page change instead to call directly the API by ajax, as it is avoided by using redux.

Comment: Ok, which library do you use to fetch data ? Redux-Thunk ?

Comment: I'm using Redux-Saga, but works in same way of Thunk, with dispatchers and reducers.